# Save created files made with a Google script to a specified Google folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating Text files with a Google script I found [from here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/12/07/downloading-file-using-button-of-dialog-box-on-google-docs/)

They save by default in my Google Drive.

I want to save them in a specific called folder called `TextFiles` in my Google drive

create text files with

```
function dlFile(str) {
  let file = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile('Hi.txt', str);

  // Create little HTML popup with the URL of the download
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('download.html');
  htmlTemplate.dataFromServerTemplate = { url: file.getDownloadUrl() };

  let html = htmlTemplate
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'download');
};

HTML
<input type="button" value="download" onclick="getUrl()" />
<script>
  function getUrl() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(download).getDownloadUrl();
  }

  function download(obj) {
    var d = document.createElement('a');
    d.href = obj.url;
    d.download = obj.filename;
    d.click();
  }
</script>
```

How to save these to an existing folder called `TextFiles`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a text file to the specific folder by modifying your script.

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let file = DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile('Hi.txt', str);
```

#### To:

```
const folderName = "TextFiles"; // Please set the folder name you want to put the file.
const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
const folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
let file = folder.createFile('Hi.txt', str);
```

- In this modification, when the folder of `folderName` is not existing, the folder of `folderName` is created as a new folder and put the file.
- If the folder of `folderName` is existing in the Shared Drive, you can use the following script.

  ```
    const folderId = "###"; // Folder ID of the folder "TextFiles";
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    let file = folder.createFile('Hi.txt', str);
  ```

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [createFile(name, content) of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content)

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this:

```
Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());
```

You must enable Drive API v2